# Loading Initial Data from a web service call

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am reading this tutorial on writing Async Actions

http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

and based on this, I have a method called fetchPosts in my action. this method first dispatches a requestPosts action, then it calls the web service and finally dispatches receivePosts with the results.

My question is from where should I call this method so that when my application loads, the data is loaded from web service?

Comment: This is a really open-ended question. The better approach for SO is to try putting them somewhere and then come back when you run into problems. That said, deciding where to put them depends on when you want the data. You have to decide what "when my application loads" means for you. Dispatch it there. Personally, I tend to default to the `componentWillMount` method of my top-most component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some options depending from app logic

**1) If you want access to posts globally, across all components**

you can put `fetchPosts` right after creating store,
 example from 
[redux/examples/shopping-cart](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/e5ea36bf50ee89060f1f3592b7fb93a6d43f004b/examples/shopping-cart/index.js#L21)

```
const store = createStore(
   reducer,
   applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)

store.dispatch(getAllProducts())
```

**2) If you want access to posts only for specific component/page**

you can put `fetchPosts` call in `componentWillMount` method of specific component.

```
componentWillMount() {
    loadData()
}
```

Some examples from redux official examples

1. [redux/examples/real-world/containers/RepoPage.js](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/d839786fc70cb0c2a47cc7b2b4833cdbd3efd9b2/examples/real-world/containers/RepoPage.js#L22)
2. [redux/examples/async/containers/App.js](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/6281114158b5c3722235fd19c31487da3bbb21e4/examples/async/containers/App.js#L16)
3. [redux/examples/real-world/containers/UserPage.js](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/d839786fc70cb0c2a47cc7b2b4833cdbd3efd9b2/examples/real-world/containers/UserPage.js#L23)